# Binary Classification Evaluator AUC Score in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataset with 2 classes (churners and non-churners) in the ratio 1:4. I used Random Forests algorithm via Spark MLlib. My model is terrible at predicting churn class and does nothing.
I use BinaryClassificationEvaluator to evaluate my model in Pyspark. The default metric for the BinaryClassificationEvaluator is AreaUnderRoc.

My code

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()

# Create an initial RandomForest model.
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", numTrees=1000,impurity="entropy")
# Train model with Training Data
rfModel = rf.fit(train_df)
rfModel.featureImportances

# Make predictions on test data using the Transformer.transform() method.
predictions = rfModel.transform(test_df)

# AUC Evaluate best model
evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print('Test Area Under Roc',evaluator.evaluate(predictions))

Test Area Under Roc 0.8672196520652589
```

and here is the confusion matrix.

[confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZ7F.png)

Since TP=0, how could be that score possible? Could this value be wrong?

I have other models which works fine,but this score makes me wonder if the others are wrong as well.

Comment: Hi, ROC-AUC evaluates results for many "thresholds" of probabilities. You see TP  = 0 since you are computing the confusion matrix with a very low threshold (perhaps is this one: if probability >=0.5 then 1 else 0 ) ; so you should lower this threshold to get other confusion matrix. If you did not get the idea let me know and I'll post this in an answer with a reproductible example, or perhaps you should post a reproductible example too so we can explain this better

Answer (score -1):

Your data might be heavily biased towards one of the classes, I would recommend using Precision or F-Measure, since it's a better metric in such situations.
Try using this:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictions)
val f1Score = metrics.fMeasureByThreshold
f1Score.collect.foreach { case (t, f) =>
  println(s"Threshold: $t, F-score: $f, Beta = 1")
}
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/BinaryClassificationMetrics.html